# Check hasClass using regex in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have few classnames like this:

```
<div class=".error .error-code-123">
```

Now I want to to check whether the *.error* class has any *.error-code-SOME_NUMBER*.

I tried something like this:

```
$(".error").hasClass(/.error-code-[0-9]/)
```

Just trying to use regex here, which does not work. How can I check the above scenario using jquery?

Comment: Is it possible for you to amend the HTML? This can be made **much** easier by storing the error code in a `data` attribute instead of a `class`. That way you know exactly how to retrieve the value, and can select the elements by it, instead of having to loop over them all and hack the `class` string around with a regex.

Comment: No @RoryMcCrossan, it is getting appended by third party api if there is some error.

Comment: Yuck. @Zenoo has about the neatest solution for this then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `classList` property of your element and test if at least one of its classes starts with  `error-code-` using [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`String#startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) :

```js
let result = Array.from($(".error")[0].classList).some(c => c.startsWith('error-code-'));
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="error error-code-123"></div>
```

Comment: This should be my clear option in the end, thanks for your answer.